# INNER JOIN Duplicate Records

Tags: mysql

**My Question & Problem**

I want to get two tables records at once.
My SQL Query is:

```
SELECT r.upliner,r.refer,r.date_time,u.username,u.name,u.sponsor
FROM referral_details r 
INNER JOIN userdetails  u ON r.upliner = u.sponsor
WHERE u.sponsor = '1122'
GROUP BY u.username
```

This works fine and I'm not getting duplicate records, but the problem is that every row has some unique values like date_time but when I run the above query I'm not getting date_time unique.

**referral_details** Table Structure

| upliner | refer | date_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1122 | 2233 | 89-444-555 |
| 1122 | 3344 | 90-555-666 |
| 1122 | 4455 | 91-666-777 |
| 1122 | 5566 | 92-777-888 |
| 1122 | 6677 | 93-888-999 |
| 1122 | 7788 | 94-999-111 |

**userdetails** Table Structure

| id | username | name | code | sponsor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | usman | Muhammad Usman | 1122 |  |
| 2 | arslan | Jackson | 2233 | 1122 |
| 3 | rehman | robo | 3344 | 1122 |
| 4 | talha | mike | 4455 | 1122 |
| 5 | mehmod | pompie | 5566 | 1122 |
| 6 | tafsil | gita | 6677 | 1122 |

When I run the above query I'm **Getting this result**

| upliner | refer | date time | sponsor | username | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1122 | 2233 | 89-444-555 | 1122 | arslan | Jackson |
| 1122 | 2233 | 89-444-555 | 1122 | mehmod | pompie |
| 1122 | 2233 | 89-444-555 | 1122 | rehman | robo |
| 1122 | 2233 | 89-444-555 | 1122 | tafsil | gita |
| 1122 | 2233 | 89-444-555 | 1122 | talha | mike |

As you can see I'm getting only usernames unique but their registered date_time is the same in all columns.

**Expected Results**

| upliner | refer | date time | sponsor | username | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1122 | 2233 | 89-444-555 | 1122 | arslan | Jackson |
| 1122 | 3344 | 90-555-666 | 1122 | mehmod | pompie |
| 1122 | 4455 | 91-666-777 | 1122 | rehman | robo |
| 1122 | 5566 | 92-777-888 | 1122 | tafsil | gita |
| 1122 | 6677 | 93-888-999 | 1122 | talha | mike |

in Expected Result, every user has its original stored value Like DateTime.

How can I achieve this? Please help me

Comment: a [mre] must be in text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question  also a dbfiddle is helpful

Comment: you might be getting same set of data for other dates too.

Comment: @nbk code improved. Please have a look

Comment: Grouping by the username groups everything by username, meaning that it will treat that as the "unique" thing and make one row per username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using `GROUP BY u.username`, it doesn't quite make sense here.

However, you will get some duplicate records if you remove it - and that's because you `INNER JOIN` on just one of the fields, while I'm assuming it should be on both the referrer and the "upliner". If you join on just the one, it will match all the "upliner" of 1122 for every user. If you also join on the users code, you should be getting the result you are looking for.

```sql
SELECT r.upliner,
       r.refer,
       r.date_time,
       u.username,
       u.name,
       u.sponsor
FROM referral_details AS r 
INNER JOIN userdetails AS u 
    ON r.upliner = u.sponsor
    AND r.refer = u.code
WHERE u.sponsor = '1122'
```

Comment: Thank you soo much and now I finally understand things. How to post a question or StackOverflow and how to join tables. Again thank you soo much.